# Why can't I add an HTML custom attribute to a visualforce page?

Tags: html, visualforce, custom-attributes

I have an  control, to which I want to add a custom html attribute called, previousValue.

The [Salesforce Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf) assures me that I can do this by prefixing the attribute name with html-.

So I have an element that appears thus:. I also have the docType="html-5.0" attribute in my page control.

However, in Eclipse I get an 'unsupported attribute' error.  I have upgraded to the latest force.com IDE; can any one tell me why this isn't working?  What else do I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, the answer to this seems to be that the salesforce developer's guide is inaccurate and the 'hmtl-' prefix is not supported by the `<apex:inputField>` component.  I can add it without a problem to an `<apex:outputPanel>` component.  Don't understand why this should be so and the whole point to using these attributes is to locate data in a relevant place and avoid complex jquery selects to find the data relative to the location at which it is required.